# Matrix as node label

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, matrices, labels

consider the following image (taken from [here](http://swizec.com/blog/week-10-the-myriad-virtues-of-wavelet-trees/swizec/6468)):

[image]

I want to adapt this image as TikZ picture.
I would represent each rectangular node of the tree as a TikZ node. 
Each node has two character-wise aligned strings as labels.
Is there a clever way, for instance using the matrix library of
TikZ, to align text of node labels character-wise, like it
was done in the picture?

I have looked at some examples, but I have not found a similar situation yet.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why not just use a mono spaced font, e.g. `\node[align=left,font=\ttfamily]{abcde\\12345};`? Do you have the code for the tree, without the "custom" styled nodes? If so, can you add that to your question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, I do not have the code of the tree. Using monospace font would be a perfect solution. However, i just wondered whether there is a more general way to make matrix-like labels, e.g. if you have sophisticated demands wrt spacing, cell alignment, separating lines etc.

Comment: By the way, do you want to use a special tree-package, like `tikz-qtree` or `forest`, or is plain TikZ fine?

Answer (score 2):

For your example, nodes with a monospaced font is sufficient, so you can use something like `node[draw,align=center,font=\ttfamily]{imimi\\23451}`.

That said, a `matrix` is just a special type of `node`, so you can actually use `node[matrix] {...}` in TikZ tree structure. See example below.

I also added a simple example of a more manual way of setting things up, placing several `\matrix` constructions relative to each other.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] {start} 
child {node[draw,align=center,font=\ttfamily]{imimi\\23451}}
child {node[draw,align=center,font=\ttfamily]{abaae\\10011}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[every matrix/.append style={ampersand replacement=\&,matrix of nodes}]
\node [matrix,draw] {a \& b \\ c \& d \\} 
child {node[matrix,draw] {a \& b \\ c \& d \\}}
child {node[matrix,draw] {a \& b \\ c \& d \\}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip


\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={on grid,node distance=1.5cm and 1cm},
                    every matrix/.append style={matrix of nodes,draw}]
\matrix (m1) {1&2\\b&c\\};
\matrix [below left=of m1] (m2) {1&2\\b&c\\};
\matrix [below right=of m1] (m3) {1&2\\b&c\\};

\draw (m1) edge (m2)
           edge (m3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```